# How to write line buffered in java?

Tags: java, file-io

In C you can set the buffering using the function

int setvbuf (FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size);

How can I set the buffering in Java so that is behaves the same as _IOLBF (for line buffering)? Which class does this?

I know that there is BufferedWriter, but this does full buffering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrintWriter with autoflush.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, /* autoflush */ true);

pw.println(somethingToPrint); // will flush as well.
```

This is not exactly the same as it will push out data whenever the buffer files (esp for very long lines) and it won't flush if you write text with newlines in it but use `print()` to print the line.

Comment: According to the documentation it seems that certain methods automatically flush, but also when the line is not complete. What I am looking for is automatic flushing only and always when a line is complete, so exactly after a \n character.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs this is the closest AFAIK. It wouldn't be too hard to implement yourself if you really need it to work this way or add flush () as required.